# Unable to pass raw JSON request body with response error "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand"

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying to make a GET request to the URI which has header **Content-Type=application/json** and has a request body which is a raw JSON type.

Below is the code I am using with RestAssured API but it throws an error in response saying "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand"

```
String Json = "{\n" +
            "    \"type\": \"estrix\",\n" +
            "    \"role_name\": \"admin\",\n" +
            "    \"id\": 001,\n" +
            "    \"start_date\": \"2018-01-01\",\n" +
            "    \"end_date\": \"2022-12-30\",\n" +
"}";
```

```
response = given().urlEncodingEnabled(true).body(Json).contentType("application/json").get(path);
```

Any pointers where might be the issue?

Comment: It works as you wrote. The error message got back from the server.  The json invalid. Delete the trailing coma after `end_date` field. I suggest use text bolcks or Java objects if it is possible to ensure json string validity.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the trailing comma, had missed to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a typo of trailing comma after end_date, Corrected it below and worked.

```
String Json = "{\n" +
            "    \"type\": \"estrix\",\n" +
            "    \"role_name\": \"admin\",\n" +
            "    \"id\": 001,\n" +
            "    \"start_date\": \"2018-01-01\",\n" +
            "    \"end_date\": \"2022-12-30\"\n" +
"}";
```